# IE Drawing methods in CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, drawing

In `<insert non-IE browser here>` there is the `<canvas>` element that allows for doing some fairly advanced drawing. In IE it's possible to draw with `<div>` elements, but that can get pretty slow if you're doing anything more than a few basic tasks.

Is there anything available in IE 5+, in pure HTML/CSS/Javascript, that can allows for basic drawing? At least the ability to draw pixels. Lines would be nice, but I'm not too greedy.

My Google searches have failed to turn up anything useful, and I strongly suspect I won't find anything, but I figured if anyone would know/it's the folks on stack overflow!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Explorer Canvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)** makes `<canvas>` available for IE6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **VML** as an alternative. Google Maps uses it to support IE.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) library.